# Scala How to Find All Unique Values from a Specific Column in a CSV?

Tags: string, scala, csv, getline

I am using Scala to read from a csv file. The file is formatted to have 3 columns each separated by a `\t` character. The first 2 columns are unimportant and the third column contains a list of comma separated identifiers stored as as strings. Below is a sample of what the input csv would look like:

```
0002ba73    US  6o7,6on,6qc,6qj,6nw,6ov,6oj,6oi,15me,6pb,6p9
002f50e4    US  6om,6pb,6p8,15m9,6ok,6ov,6qc,6oo,15me
004b5edc    US  6oj,6nz,6on,6om,6qc,6ql,6p6,15me
005cc990    US  6pb,6qf,15me,6og,6nx,6qc,6om,6ok
005fe1ea    US  15me,6p0,6ql,6ok,6ox,6ol,6o5,6qj
00777555    US  6pb,15me,6nw,6rk,6qc,6ov,6qj,6o0,6oj,6ok,6on,6p6,6nx,15m9
00cbcc7d    US  6oj,6qc,6qg,6pb,6ol,6p6,6ov,15me
010254a6    US  6qc,6pb,6nw,6nx,15me,6o0,6ok,6p8
011b905c    US  6oj,6nw,6ov,15me,6qc,6ow,6ql,6on,6qi,6qe
011fffa6    US  15me,6ok,6oj,6p6,6pb,6on,6qc,6ov,6oo,6nw,6oc
```

I want to read in the csv, get rid of the first two columns, and create a List that contains one instance of each unique identifier code found in the third column, so running the code on the above data should return the result `List(6on, 6qc, 6qj, 6nw, 6ov, 6oj, 6oi, 15me, 6pb, 6p9, 6p8, 15m9, 6ok, 6oo, 6nz, 6om, 6ql, 6p6, 6qf, 6og, 6nx, 6p0, 6ox, 6ol, 6o5, 6rk, 6o0, 6qg, 6ow, 6qi, 6qe, 6oc)`

I have the following code which returns a List containing every distinct value found anywhere in the csv file:

```
val in_file = new File("input_file.csv")
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(in_file, "utf-8")
val labels = try source.getLines.mkString("\t") finally source.close()
val labelsList: List[String] = labels.split("[,\t]").map(_.trim).toList.distinct
```

Using the above input, my code returns `labelsList` with a value of `List(0002ba73-e60c-4ffb-9131-c1612b904658, US, 6o7, 6on, 6qc, 6qj, 6nw, 6ov, 6oj, 6oi, 15me, 6pb, 6p9, 002f50e4-48cc-4b14-bb80-0502068b6161, 6om, 6p8, 15m9, 6ok, 6oo, 004b5edc-c0cc-4ffd-bef3-980bd92b92e6, 6nz, 6ql, 6p6, 005cc990-83dc-4e63-a4b6-58f38241e8fd, 6qf, 6og, 6nx, 005fe1ea-b918-48a3-a495-1f8ac12935ba, 6p0, 6ox, 6ol, 6o5, 00777555-83d4-401e-861b-5892f3aa3e1c, 6rk, 6o0, 00cbcc7d-1b48-4c5c-8141-8fc8f62b7b07, 6qg, 010254a6-2ef0-4a24-aa4d-3cc6656a55de, 011b905c-fbf3-441a-8912-a94cc0fe8a1d, 6ow, 6qi, 6qe, 011fffa6-0b9f-4d88-8ced-ce1cc864984f, 6oc)`

How can I get my code to run properly and ignore anything contained within the first 2 columns of the csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the first two columns and then split the third by the comma.
Finally a `toSet` will get rid of the duplicate identifiers.

```
val f = Source.fromFile("input_file.csv")
val lastColumns = f.getLines().map(_.split("\t")(2))
val uniques = lastColumns.flatMap(_.split(",")).toSet
uniques foreach println
```

Comment: That code creates an individual set for the third column contents of every row.  The goal here is to create one set that contains every unique identifier that appeared in the third column of any row.

Answer (score 1):

Using Scala 2.13 resource management.

```
util.Using(io.Source.fromFile("input_file.csv")){
  _.getLines()
   .foldLeft(Array.empty[String]){
     _ ++ _.split("\t")(2).split(",")
   }.distinct.toList
}
//res0: scala.util.Try[List[String]] =
// Success(List(6o7, 6on, 6qc, 6qj, 6nw, 6ov, 6oj, 6oi, 15me, 6pb, 6p9, 6om, 6p8, 15m9, 6ok, 6oo, 6nz, 6ql, 6p6, 6qf, 6og, 6nx, 6p0, 6ox, 6ol, 6o5, 6rk, 6o0, 6qg, 6ow, 6qi, 6qe, 6oc))
```

The `.toList` can be dropped if an `Array` result is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do , Am doing on a sample `DF`, you can replace with yours

```
val Df = Seq(("7369", "SMITH" , "2010-12-17", "800.00"), ("7499", "ALLEN","2011-02-20", "1600.00")).toDF("empno", "ename","hire_date", "sal")

val reqCols = Seq(2)
val finalDf = Df.select(reqCols map Df.columns map col: _*)
finalDf.show
```

[image]

**Note** : This is `0-based index`, so pass 2 to get third column.

If you want distinct values from your desired column.you can use **distinct** along with **mkstring**

```
val Df = Seq(("7369", "SMITH" , "2010-12-17", "800.00"), ("7499", "ALLEN","2011-02-20", "1600.00"), ("7499", "ALLEN","2011-02-20", "1600.00")).toDF("empno", "ename","hire_date", "sal")

val reqCols = Seq(2)
val distinctValues = Df.select(reqCols map Df.columns map col: _*).distinct.collect.mkString(",").filterNot("[]".toSet)
println(distinctValues)
```

Dates are duplicate , above code is removing duplicates.

[image]

Comment: This question is not using spark.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using regex

```
val data = scala.io.Source.fromFile("source.txt").getLines()
data.toList.flatMap {
  line => """\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)""".r.findAllMatchIn(line).map( x => x.group(1).split(",").toList)
  }.flatten.distinct

// res0: List[String] = List(6o7, 6on, 6qc, 6qj, 6nw, 6ov, 6oj, 6oi, 15me, 6pb, 6p9, 6om, 6p8, 15m9, 6ok, 6oo, 6nz, 6ql, 6p6, 6qf, 6og, 6nx, 6p0, 6ox, 6ol, 6o5, 6rk, 6o0, 6qg, 6ow, 6qi, 6qe, 6oc)
```